# how to do next page in richfaces 4 togglepanel (which is different to the showcase)?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf-2, richfaces, toggle

I have a togglepanel and a a4j commandButton, I would like to submit the form and next page on complete.

But It is not working, it won't next page but submit only. Here is the code.

```
<a4j:commandButton action="#{inputData.inputId}" value="Next">
  <f:param name="id" value="#{userBean.id}" />
  <rich:toggleControl targetItem="@next" event="complete"/>
</a4j:commandButton>
```

I tried oncomplete="#{rich:component('tooglepanelid')}.next();" too, not working too.. where can i find the togglepanel api doc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the API here: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/

togglepanel: http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_X/vdldoc/rich/togglePanel.html

Although be warned it is still work in progress.

If you change the event to a click does it work? I don't think complete is a valid value as oncomplete is not a valid JS event for the 'parent' component. But not sure...

Also try putting in a messages tag to see if there are any errors.

As for this:

> I tried oncomplete="#{rich:component('tooglepanelid')}.next();"

I don't think next() is valid JS function for that toggle panel, based on the [RF component reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_0_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Panels.html#sect-Component_Reference-richtogglePanel-JavaScript_API) these functions look to be the ones you need to use:

> The <rich:togglePanel> component can be controlled through the
>   JavaScript API. The JavaScript API provides the following functions,
>   which are common to all switchable panels:
>
> 1. getItems() Return an array of the items contained in the toggle panel.
> 2. getItemsNames() Return an array of the names of the items contained in
>      the toggle panel.
> 3. switchToItem(itemName) Switch to and display the
>      item identified by the itemName string passed as a parameter.
> 4. firstItem(), prevItem(), nextItem(), lastItem() Switch to and display
>      the first item, the previous item, the next item, or the last item.

Comment: Great for the API you provided! BTW, switchType="server"   and   oncomplete="#{rich:component('tpid')}.switchToItem('panelitemid');" works. There is a overhead since the whole toggle panel has to transfer again and again. Any idea to improve this ?

Comment: can you not have switchType="ajax"? Then just in the same component you have the oncomplete attr include the rerender attr and only rerender a components id you want refreshed

Comment: There is still something wrong in other page. Finally this is my solution, switchType="ajax" and activeItem="#{inputBean.tabname}"...by changing the activeItem, i am able to simulate the effect...thanks for your answer though. very good reference.